# Delete custom option using store_id and option_id

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I want to delete custom option when given store_id and option_id is same.

Currently magneto have this code

```
foreach ($product->getOptions() as $option) 
{       

    $option->getValueInstance()->deleteValue($option->getId());
    $option->deletePrices($option->getId());
    $option->deleteTitles($option->getId());
    $option->delete();
}
```

and I tried this code for delete

```
foreach ($product->getOptions() as $option) 
{       
    $allStores = Mage::app()->getStores();
    foreach ($allStores as $_eachStoreId => $val)
    {
        if($_storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore($_eachStoreId)->getCode() == $importData['store'])
        {
                $option->getValueInstance()->deleteValue($option->getId());
                $option->deletePrices($option->getId());
                $option->deleteTitles($option->getId());
                    $option->delete();
            }
        }
}
```

But it will delete all the custom option when `option_id` is same and not check for the `store_id`

So please help me how can I delete custom option when specific store_id and option_id?

Comment: what does it mean option_id is same?

Comment: i checked that when magneto have multi store view at that time custom option is stored in the `catalog_product_option_title` and there is a field like **option_title_id,option_id,store_id,title** so i want to delete custom option when the option have a specific `store_id` an `option_id` using this `$option->getValueInstance()->deleteValue($option->getId());` it will delete using only option_id    so you have any idea how can i modify this deleteValue()function @JevgeniSmirnov

Comment: Well generally the option_id should be unique value for each option. So your product generally  already has options for specific store view. Try to debug what value of product->getStore do you have? It might be that you would need to reload product for each store.

Comment: One more thing I thought: you might not delete option itself, but option value!

Answer (score 1):

I'v changed your code a little bit. It should work faster and properly now. So check it out:

```
$allStores = Mage::app()->getStores(false,true);
foreach ($product->getOptions() as $option) 
{           
    foreach ($allStores as $_eachStoreCode => $val)
    {
        if(strcasecmp($_eachStoreCode,$importData['store']) == 0)
        {
                $option->getValueInstance()->deleteValue($option->getId());
                $option->deletePrices($option->getId());
                $option->deleteTitles($option->getId());
                    $option->delete();
            }
        }
}
```

It seems that [this link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/43313/#t254127) might be also helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the code but am getting a foreign key constraint error on this.

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento161`.`catalog_product_option_price`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_OPT_PRICE_OPT_ID_CAT_PRD_OPT_OPT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`option_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_option` (`option_id`) ON DELETE C).
Any help ?